# Need to Execute test in both parallel and in Sequence

Tags: javascript, protractor

I got 4 test cases in protractor of which I need to run 2 in parallel and 2 in sequence. I want to run the first 2 test in sequence and the next two test in parallel. Can any one please suggest me how to do this? I don't know how to do it. My conf.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    framework: 'jasmine',

 specs: [
         './test/supplier-portal-partner.js',// Sequence
        './test/supplier-portal-admin.js',// Sequence
        './test/supplier-portal-Language-PT.js',// Parallel
        './test/supplier-portal-Language-ES.js',// Parallel

        ],
    capabilities:[ {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 1,

        'platform': 'ANY',
        'version': 'ANY',
        'chromeOptions': {

            prefs: {
                download: {
                    'prompt_for_download': false,
                    'directory_upgrade': true,
                    'default_directory': 'C:/Users/jasharma/gitrepo/supplier-portal/download'
                }
            }
        }

    }],
 http://qaswarm.community.nw.ops.here.com:4444/wd/hub",



    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 10000 * 250 //250 Seconds
    }
};
```

Thanks in adavance

Comment: When you say Parallel do you mean it will open two browsers for  `Language-PT` and `Language-ES` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below multicapabilities configuration,

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        sequential: true,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        specs: ['./test/supplier-portal-partner.js',
                './test/supplier-portal-admin.js']
    },
    {
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 2,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        specs: './test/supplier-portal-Language-PT.js',
               './test/supplier-portal-Language-ES.js']
    }
]
```

Above configuration will launch 3 browser instances and executes 1st set of specs in sequence and 2nd set of specs in two different browsers simultaneously.

Comment: Where can we get the info regarding setting a conf.js. I mean all options which we can include in a conf and what they do.